# rails select tag with multiple values pre selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a multiple select box.  select box will contain all the stores in the DB but the ones that the user belongs to will be selected.

I'm half way there.  I got a select box which has all the stores in the database.  I'm unable to select the ones that the user belongs to.

I have the following:

```
<%= select_tag 'stores[]', options_for_select(@stores.map {|s| [s.store_name, s.store_id]}, 
:selected => @user.stores.map {|j| [j.store_name, j.store_id]}), :multiple => true, :size => 
10 %>
```

I have a map with stores that a user belongs to. it is in:

```
@user.stores
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

after a fair amount of trial and error the following worked for me:

```
<%= select_tag 'stores[]', options_for_select(@stores.map { |s| [s.store_name, s.store_id] }, @user.stores.pluck(:id)), multiple: true, size: 10 %>
```

Comment: FYi, just a tiny spacesave/nice Ruby - you can shorten the selected option from @user.stores.map {|j| j.store_id } to @user.stores.map(&:store_id)

Comment: Thanks bro! But I think that you can use `@user.store_ids` instead `pluck`

Answer (score 16):

Another way of doing this would be to use the [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) helper method. It will look something like this:

```
<%= select_tag 'stores[]', options_from_collection_for_select(@stores, :store_id, :store_name, [4,5,6]), multiple: true, size: '10%' %>
```

Comment: I don't know if this was available when the question was asked but this should be the approved answer IMO.

Comment: My pleasure @yagudaev. I was dissapointed that the list of selected entries requires to be ids and the :store_id cannot be applied to it :(