# Post values from a multiple select

Tags: html, html-select

How can I post values from a multiple select in a form? When I hit submit none of the selected  values are posted.

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <select id="inscompSelected" multiple="multiple" class="lstSelected">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute.

Since this is a multiple select, at the HTTP level, the client just sends multiple name/value pairs with the same name, you can observe this yourself if you use a form with `method="GET": someurl?something=1&something=2&something=3`.

In the case of PHP, Ruby, and some other library/frameworks out there, you would need to add square braces (`[]`) at the end of the name. The frameworks will parse that string and wil present it in some easy to use format, like an array.

Apart from manually parsing the request there's no language/framework/library-agnostic way of accessing multiple values, because they all have different APIs

For PHP you can use:

```
<select name="something[]" id="inscompSelected" multiple="multiple" class="lstSelected">
```

Comment: Since it's a multiple select, you want the name to end with `[]` (so that it's posted as an array).

Comment: I would also add that if you're using something like PHP you can always dump out the `$_POST` to see what variable are held after the submit.

Comment: Adding `[]` at the end of the name is a PHP idiom, it is not required by HTML and it's not used by other languages/frameworks.

Comment: agreed with @Sergey. So a question still remains. "what is the  language agnostic way of accessing the multiple selected values on server side?"

Comment: @Ejay: At the HTTP level, the client just sends multiple name/value pairs with the same name, you can observe this yourself if you use a form with `method="GET"`: `someurl?something=1&something=2&something=3`. The library/framework you're using just parses that string and presents it in some easy to use format. Apart from manually parsing the request there's no language/framework/library-agnostic way of accessing multiple values, because they all have different APIs.

Comment: @Biotox has it nailed,   always use a 'sample' form to post with a var_dump just to see what happens!

Comment: Completely depends on the server-side.  As Sergey said, the HTML form just posts multiple values with the same name.  In MVC, your controller method's parameter with the same name could be either a string or a string array.   If you make it a string, then it will convert the values into a comma separated list and pass that as the string.  Meanwhile, if you simply change the parameter type from string to string[] without changing anything else, then MVC will pass the individual item strings instead of concatenating them into a single comma-separated string.

Comment: For anyone using Rails, the convention is the same - just append [] to the HTML select name. So in HTML <select multiple="multiple" name="el_name[]">, and in controller you can access it as params[:el_name]. Rails-specific Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654675/rails-select-with-multiple-options-only-sends-one and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196522/1796742. Totally agree, though, that each framework handles it in own way.

Comment: @Triynko what do you refer when you say MVC? The chosen/used MVC-framework or you mean that those conventions are defined in the MVC architectural pattern? (I ask because I couldn't find references to it and until now I thought that those were arbitrary convention invented for PHP)

Comment: @rocketHazmat  solution "name to end with []" worked for me (php environnement). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

try this : here select is your select element

```
let select = document.getElementsByClassName('lstSelected')[0],
    options = select.options,
    len = options.length,
    data='',
    i=0;
while (i<len){
    if (options[i].selected)
        data+= "&" + select.name + '=' + options[i].value;
    i++;
}
return data;
```

Data is in the form of query string i.e.name=value&name=anotherValue

Answer (score 0):

The route I'm about to take is to add a hidden field in the form, and modify its value using a similar algorithm to @Chin2 's above in the onchange event of the multiple select element. Then maybe remove the name field from the select element.

```
function selChangedEventHandler()
{
    select = document.getElementById("multiselect_id");
   
    options = select.options,
    len = options.length,
    data='',
    i=0;
    first = true;
    while ( i < len )
    {
        if (options[i].selected)
        {
            if ( !first )
            {
                data += '+';
            }
            data += options[i].value;
            first = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    hidden = document.getElementById('hiddentext_id');
    hidden.value = data;
}
```