# How to handle lists with multiple select in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a **multiple select** something like this..

```
<select multiple="multiple" th:field="*{names}">
 <option value="abc">abc</option>
 <option value="def">def</option>
 <option value="ghi">ghi</option>
 <option value="jkl">jkl</option>
</select>
```

where `names` is the name of the list which looks like this..

```
List<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, I would like the user to select multiple names and then put into the `names` list.
Consider that I have selected

1. abc
2. def
3. ghi

When I am submitting the form, I see that the data is sent like this..

```
names=abc&names=def&names=ghi
```

however, I want it to be like `names[0]=abc&names[1]=def&names[2]=ghi`.

**P.S.** I don't want to use Ajax form sending.

Comment: If you don't use Javascript, that's how the browser will send the fields. There is no changing that

Comment: I mean I would like to use normal sending instead of via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it important to have the submitted form's query string look a certain way?  Is it because you are processing this form with a different framework other than Spring MVC?

Based on your tags of spring-mvc, Spring expects the `names=abc&names=def&names=ghi`. That is the data for the `names` `<select>` form field, which is a **single** form field with multiple values.  Internally, Spring will correctly map it to the `names` property for a form-backing bean.

To get `names[0]=abc&names[1]=def&names[2]=ghi`, you will need 3 `<select>` elements in your HTML to represent each unique field name (i.e. `names[0]`, `names[1]`, etc), which is something I doubt you want.

As far as I know, that's the behavior of HTML and can't be changed.

I also did a quick search and was reminded that PHP requires the name of multi-select fields to end in `[]` for it to be parsed as an array.  But that's a PHP-only quirk.  That's the closest reason I can think for your original requirement.  However, that would have required something like this instead:  `names[]=abc&names[]=def&names[]=ghi`.  And I doubt you can mimic that with Spring/Thymeleaf since those are not valid property name characters.  See this for details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616681/1034436 (noting the comments)