# Getting all items in a select list to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I have two multi select list one which holds a full list of names and the second one holds the names that were selected from the first list. The names are stored in Vue array which populates the names into the second select list, but when I submit the form that this is all held I get null for the result of the values in the second multi select.

```
<select multiple style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
      <option v-for="item in Selected" name="Signatures" selected>{{ item }</option>
</select>

var signatures = new Vue({
        el: '#signatures',
        data: {
            Selected: []
        }
    })
```

Below is my controller, the model is not needed in this portion as the data is just going to the server side to be stored into variables for next page.

```
public ActionResult LoadTextFile(MainVM vM)
        {
            string size = Request.Form["Size"];
            string document = Request.Form["Document"];
            string tribute = Request.Form["Tribute"];
            string date = Request.Form["date"];
            string signatures = Request.Form["Signatures"];
            return View();
        }
```

I'm trying to get the values of the select list using `Request.form("Signatures");`

I'm hoping there is either a way for me to submit all of the values in the select list over using a JavaScript framework or C#.

Comment: show your model and controller action code as well

Comment: @RajeshG I have added my controller but the model is not used in this portion of the code and should not be used as I don't want any of this data to be stored on the server.

Comment: Did you check form data in network tab from developer tool?

Comment: yeah and I'm seeing that data is being transferred, but the problem is that signatures is returning null, but the rest of the variables hold the data that was selected on the client side.

Comment: Also, if Signatures is multiple select then it should be List of string right?

Comment: You are saying that it should be List<string> right?

Comment: yes that make sense!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204946/discussion-between-dominik-willaford-and-rajesh-g).

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616659/post-values-from-a-multiple-select) I realized that what I need to do was add the square brackets to the name.

The end result was:

```
<select multiple style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" name="Signatures[]">
                        <option v-for="item in Selected" selected>{{ item }}</option>
                    </select>
string signatures = Request.Form["Signatures[]"];
```

Comment: still you are getting signatures as string. is that okay for you?

Comment: yeah that is fine I can split them apart using commas then