# rails input selected values from params to select_tag (multiple => true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to keep the `select_tag(:multiple => true)` options to be selected which were selected by user once search is performed

```
<%= select_tag 'values[]', method_for_options_for_select, :class => 'some-class', :multiple => true, :size => 6 %>
```

Suppose a user select 4 values from the select tag then for values should be selected,
How can we pass this 4 values to the select_tag?

I tried using `:selected => params['values[]']` but this doesnt works for multiple true

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196382/rails-select-tag-with-multiple-values-pre-selected) and [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002300)

Something like following

```
<%= select_tag 'values[]', 
options_for_select(@stores.map {|s| [s.store_name, s.store_id]}, 
@user.stores.map {|j| j.store_id}),
:class => 'some-class', :multiple => true, :size => 6 %>
```

Comment: If you are getting params['values'] as an array on page replace `@user.stores.map {|j| j.store_id}` with `params['values']`